# Heroku/Git -a switch and remote -v not working

Tags: git, heroku, command-line

I’m following these [Heroku instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)  on pushing code to git. I actually used it before but the `-a` switch isn't working anymore.

On the cli:

```
$ heroku login>>I successfully logged in
$ heroku create myAppsName
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m “bla bla bla”
$ git status>>On Branch Master nothing to commit
$ heroku git:remote -a myAppsName
```

I keep getting:

> error: unknown switch ‘a’

[image: heroku -a instructions]

I also tried running `$ git remote -v` to see if my app is there but nothing is returned. However I checked the Heroku console and my app is sitting right there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran:

```
$ git remote add heroku myAppsName
```

and it worked

after that when I ran

```
$ git remote -v
```

I got the correct response of:

```
heroku myAppsName (fetch)
heroku myAppsName (push)
```